# Context free grammar for pattern /aaa/{id}

Tags: pattern-matching, context-free-grammar, parser-generator

can someone tell me what the CFG for this pattern is: `/var/{id}`

Over here, var can be repeated many times, but the pattern always ends with `{id}`

Therefore, these are all valid cases:

```
/var/var/{id}

/var/var/var/var/{id}

/var/{id}
```

I've gotten this grammar till now:

```
start::= token

token::= token expr token

token::= "/"

expr::= "var" | "{id}"
```

But I don't think its right. Help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there! The grammar you have right now will produce strings like `/var/var/var/{id}/` but also `/{id}/var/var/{id}/var/`. So what you need to do is remove `{id}` from the `expr` rule. But then you still need to tack on `{id}` at the end to fit the definition of your language, and this can be done in the `start` rule. The resulting grammar is then:

```
start::= token "{id}"
token::= token expr token
token::= "/"
expr::= "var"
```